# filter php variable for specific bbcode string - wrap matches inside of divs?

Tags: php, filter, preg-match, word-wrap

hey guys,
my php variable $content holds html!
i want to filter this $content for

`[q=SomeQuestoin]` and `[a=SomeAnswer]`

and wrap each match inside of a div.question and div.answer.

So whenever this `[q=Some Question][a=Some Answer]` structure is found in $content i want to put out this.

```
<div class="qanda">
    <div class="question">
        Some Question
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
        Some Answer
    </div>  
</div>
```

Is that possible? Important is that the Qustion Text or the Answer Text could hold html tags as well. like `<p>` or `<b>` etc.

update:

```
    $q_regex = '/\[q=([^"]+?)]/is'; 
    $q_output = '<div class="qanda"><div class="queston">$1</div>'; 
    $content = preg_replace($q_regex, $q_output, $content);

    $a_regex = '/\[a=([^"]+?)]/is'; 
    $a_output = '<div class="answer">$1</div></div>'; 
    $content = preg_replace($a_regex, $a_output, $content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.spotlesswebdesign.com/blog.php?id=12

tutorial on using regex to do bbcode parsing. people would recommend using a bbcode parser module however. should be safe to regex since you are not using nesting and whatnot.

EDIT

possible but tricky. could be error prone. something like this maybe:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\[q=(.+?)].+?\[a=(.+?)]/is', '<div class="qanda"><div class="question">$1</div><div class="answer">$2</div></div>', $subject);
```

Comment: also, don't let users enter their own html tags for content on your site, otherwise you will be open to XXS hacks on your site

Comment: I wouldn't let users to enter this stuff. Only admins can enter this in the backend.

Comment: Okay, well you may want to have two field in your database for this. One field will contain the unmodified version for editing, and the second field will contain the parsed version. This way you will not have the overhead of having to parse the text each time someone visits your site. depend on what exactkly you are doing though.

Comment: yeah, that's exaclty the case. I have this database structure.

Comment: thank you... I managed to do it but probably in a rather bad way. Is there a better solution for wrapping both replacements inside of the `div.qanda`? I'm able to replace `[q=something]` and `[a=something]`. However I need to find a solid solution to wrap both replacements into another div like in my example above. Any good solution for that? I updated my post!

Comment: Moreover, is there also a way to make sure that there is nothing else inside of this `div.qanda` then `div.question` and `div.answer`. So if this structure of Q&Q is found i want to have a `div.qanda` with a `div.question` and a `div.answer` inside (exaclty as posted above. However imagine I type `[q=something]<p>hey</p>[a=test]`... in this case the `<p>hey</p>` should be removed. It shouldn't be allowed inside of `div.qanda`.